# Sort array of object if value exists

Tags: javascript

Below is my sort function but I want to display the ones with a code to be at the top. I want to sort my array of objects by code, then by description. Right now, the items without a code is being placed at the top of the order.

```
data = [
 {
  code: "1.1",
  description: "aaa"
 },
 {
  code: "",
  description: "bbb"
 },
 {
  code: "1.2",
  description: "ccc"
 }
]


  let sortedData = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    let codeA = a.code
    let codeB = b.code
    let descriptionA = a.description.toLowerCase()
    let descriptionB = b.description.toLowerCase()

    if (codeA < codeB) return -1
    if (codeA > codeB) return 1
    if (descriptionA < descriptionB) return -1
    if (descriptionA > descriptionB) return 1
    return 0
  })

  return sortedData
```

Current order:

`["bbb", "aaa", "ccc"]`

Expected order:

`["aaa", "ccc", "bbb"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Using the xor `^` operator, we can check to see if one of the codes is falsy while the other is truthy.  In this case, falsy being blank.  If this is true, the one with a blank should be greater than the other so it sorts after it.
- Otherwise, subtract the codes, then the descriptions for normal sorting.

```js
var data = [
 {
  code: "1.1",
  description: "aaa"
 },
 {
  code: "",
  description: "bbb"
 },
 {
  code: "1.2",
  description: "ccc"
 }
];


  let sortedData = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    let codeA = a.code;
    let codeB = b.code;
    let descriptionA = a.description.toLowerCase();
    let descriptionB = b.description.toLowerCase();
    
    if (codeA ^ codeB) {
      return !codeA ? 1 : -1;
    }
    
    return codeA.localeCompare(codeB) || descriptionA.localeCompare(descriptionB);
  });

  console.log(sortedData)
```

Comment: What does `'aaa' - 'bbb'` equal? This does not sort the description strings correctly in cases where the code is equal. It looks like it works because they are already sorted.

Comment: @MarkMeyer fixed it to use the localeCompare properly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make `""` appear at the end is just to prefix the compare values, so if the code is "", the value becomes `"B"`, if it's `1.1` it become `A1.1`,  so `A1.1` < `B`..

Doing this is also very easy to modify to do all sort of fancy sorting, eg. Lets say you wanted to sort alphabetically, but wanted all `K's` at the start, and all `B's` at the end, strange thing to do.  But very easy to make happen.  I suppose you could call it sorting with exceptions.

Here is a working example.

```js
const data = [
 {
  code: "1.1",
  description: "aaa"
 },
 {
  code: "",
  description: "bbb"
 },
 {
  code: "1.2",
  description: "ccc"
 }
];

data.sort((
  { code: code1, description: desc1 },
  { code: code2, description: desc2 }
) => {
  code1 = (code1 === "" ? "B" : "A") + code1;
  code2 = (code2 === "" ? "B" : "A") + code2;
  return code1.localeCompare(code2) ||
    desc1.localeCompare(desc2);
});


console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test case is a little lax and makes it hard to spot some bugs.  You are usually better off using `localeCompare` to compare strings. You can make a case for two very plain, but readable `if` statements followed by a `localeCompare` of the strings:

Here's a few extra test cases

```js
let data = [{
    code: "1.1",
    description: "ddd"
  },
  {
    code: "1.101",
    description: "ccc"
  },
  {
    code: "",
    description: "eee"
  },
  {
    code: "1.2",
    description: "De"
  },
  {
    code: "1.1",
    description: "aaa"
  },
  {
    code: "",
    description: "bbb"
  },
  {
    code: "1.2",
    description: "ccc"
  },
  {
    code: "1.2",
    description: "AbcD"
  }
]

data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.code && !b.code) return -1
  if (b.code && !a.code) return 1

  return a.code.localeCompare(b.code) || a.description.localeCompare(b.description)
})
console.log(data)
```

:

Answer (score 0):

Since your second code is empty you will compare an empty string and Javascript will cast your `Float` to a `String`. Oddly if you compare any string if it is smaller than any other string it will always return `true`! The opposite is also true - if you compare it to be bigger than any other string it will always return `false`.

```
"" < "1.1" // return true
"1.1" < "" // return true!

"" > "1.1" // return false
"1.1" > "" // return false!
```

To solve your problem you could add two additional checks before your other checks

```
if (codeA === "" && codeA.length < codeB.length) return 1;
if (codeB === "" && codeA.length > codeB.length) return -1;
```

If codeA or codeB is a `String` you can simply compare the length of the strings.